# Getting logged out of route53 defined url

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, dns, couchbase, amazon-route53

I have created a record set in amazon route53, which is for Couchbase console. However, if I use this url, I'm logged out within a minute(variable time < 60sec in general) while this does not happen if I use the IP address directly. Can someone please explain what might be happening?

`Config:
Type: Ipv4
Alias: no
Ttl: 60 sec
value: 2 IPs
Routing policy:simple`

PS: This started happening recently. Initially it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a quick and easy experiment you can make to see why this happens. Since you have 2 nodes in your cluster (say `N1` and `N2`), try the following (You'll need the `EditThisCookie` extension for Chrome, or any similar):

1. access and log in the web console through `N1`.
2. copy the cookies created in this page by exporting them with the `EditThisCookie` tool.
3. open the `N2` web console's login page. Instead of logging in, paste the cookies copied from `N1` by importing it with the `EditThisCookie` tool.
4. refresh the page and see what happens.
5. you should still be seeing the login page.

So, what we see here is that the session tokens are not shared between nodes. I don't know if there is any config that would enable that. I also don't know why it once worked.

Finally, the problem is caused by the [route53's simple routing behaviour](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-simple). Each DNS request will receive all the IPs in the record in a random order. Assuming the [behaviour of Chromium based browsers](https://serverfault.com/questions/327708/how-browsers-handle-multiple-ips/328321#328321), whenever a timeout happens in a request to the first node, your browser would try to hit the second one, which wouldn't authenticate the request.

**How to fix**: add a single node to the DNS record should do the trick.